# How can I sync an animated gif from Photos.app on a Mac to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, macos, photos.app

I have some animated gifs in the Photos library on my Mac. When I sync them to my iPhone (using iTunes) they either don't transfer at all, or they show up as jpegs of the first frame of the gif.

I've tried sending them to myself using Messages.app. This works, but they get shrunk to a postage stamp size that looks small even on the phone screen. I want a way to send them full size, and to keep them synced with my Photos library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Photos appears to support GIF but not animated GIF.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264

I suggest you try a different cloud solution for your animated GIFs like Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That support article does not specify whether GIF animation is supported or not.

Comment: @Robert Well, if Apple doesn't specifically say they _do_ support it, and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, I found that the app "Send Anywhere" (for both Mac and iPhone) does what you want.

You will be able to send photos or animated pics directly without hassle. I tried it myself, the animated pics are all frozen when I tried to preview in iPhone photos. However, when I tried to send the pics over with a chat app, the animation works well! So to answer your question, don't complicate, just download that app!

Answer (score 0):

This must be another bug form Apple. If I download a animated GIF from Safari to Photos on iPhone I can see the animation in Photos for iOS. If I import the GIF in Photos.App on my Mac it is also displayed correctly as an animation on Mac. Importing the GIF, it is deleted from the iPhone Photo.App.
If I then sync back my iPhone using iTunes with my Mac, the GIF is synced back but on the Photo.App on the iPhone it now appears as a static picture....
Just another Apple bug.

The only workaround for me is to export a copy of the GIF on my Dropbox. This works perfectly without these stupid Apple-Bugs.

Comment: When you run into an Apple bug, the best thing to do is to provide feedback at https://www.apple.com/feedback/ .  Remember, Apple doesn't monitor this site.